# How to post data with special characters in LOGIC APPS in a POST API call to D365?

Tags: logic, odata, aps

We are experiencing difficulties  to save some data through POST API calls to D365, we can't send the '/' character as D365 says it breaks the query syntax.

The body has this line:

> "teka_codigopostal@odata.bind": "/teka_codigopostals(teka_codigo='03004-ALICANTE/ALACANT')"

and the character <kbd>/</kbd> leads to the error. How can D365 admits that character in the value in a correct way? We tried to codify the character but was useless.

Codify the character in some ways but was useless.